# Other actions occurring when sprite is tapped; how to prevent

Tags: ios, swift, button, sprite-kit

I'm building a game that is primarily played by tapping the screen (anywhere). I have currently added a settings button that when tapped, opens up a settings window.

Problem is, when the settings button is tapped, interaction happens in the game too. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

My settings screen works in conjunction with a settings function and the override touches began function through a boolean expression.

The game is played through a UITapGestureRecognizer that was added to the view in didMoveToView.

```
/* Game Interaction & Playability */
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tapped:"))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

/* Settings Button Interaction */
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let positionInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)

        if let name = touchedNode.name {
            if name == "Settings" {
                if settingsOpen == false {
                    settings()
                } else {
                    settings()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only thing I can think of doing is creating a smaller view and placing it above the main view at the top of the screen and attaching the SKSpriteNode button to it. I would imagine that since the button would then be part of a different view, I wouldn't get the conflicting of taps. But before I go through with this change, if anyone has a more simple solution, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you've got a couple gesture recognizers working here. You don't actually need to add a recognizer to the view to know if someone is tapping it. That's handled already for you (hence the reason why `touchesBegan` works without adding another recognizer).

I would say remove that extra recognizer, and move the code for `tapped:` to your `touchesBegan`.

Comment: Worked perfect, had to play with it a little in the touchesBegan but got it working. Thanks!